# WPF - Observablecollection binded DataGrid not updating when i add item from other window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Its my first time with WPF. I already seen many questions but couldn't get the right answer. Scenario is that I have ObservableCollection of order which is implemented by ViewModel. Here is the code

```
namespace WpfApplication2.ViewModels
{
public class ViewModel : ObservableCollection<Order>
{
  static ObservableCollection<Order> orderlist = new ObservableCollection<Order>();

    public ParameterCommand ParameterCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.ParameterCommand = new ParameterCommand(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
             Order o = new Order();
             o.Imei = "Person"+ i;
             o.price = i*20;
             o.Cust_ID = i;


             Add(o);
        }

    }



    public void ParameterMethod(Order order)
    {
        Order o = new Order();
        o.Imei = order.Imei;
        o.price = order.price;
        o.Cust_ID = order.Cust_ID;


        Add(o);

    }
}
}
```

Now I have the Main Window which have the Datagrid binded by above viewmodel 
MainWindow.xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="359.388" Width="630.791">
<Window.Resources>
    <view:Order x:Key="order"></view:Order>
    <model:ViewModel x:Key="modelview"/>  

    </Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource modelview}}" >
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Margin="48,26,0,0" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource modelview}}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="235" Width="373">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding Imei,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Cutomer ID"  Binding="{Binding Cust_ID,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Price"  Binding="{Binding price,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource order}}" Margin="490,69,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Imei, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource order}}" Margin="490,119,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Cust_ID, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource order}}" Margin="490,165,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=price, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>


    <Button Content="NEW" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,276,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Command="{Binding ParameterCommand, Source={StaticResource modelview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource order}}"  Height="25"/>
    <Button Content="NEW" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="239,276,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

</Grid>
```

now when i add the values from main window text boxes to ObservableCollection it is updated in the datagrid but when i use other separate window for adding item in ObservableCollection it got added in it but datagrid is not updated. Can you please help me out
**EDIT:**
here is the xaml of the window I am adding item to ObservableCollection

```
    Title="New" Height="300" Width="300">

<Window.Resources>
    <view:Order x:Key="order"></view:Order>
    <model:ViewModel x:Key="modelview"/>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Imei, Mode=TwoWay}"  Height="23" Margin="83,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Cust_ID, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="23" Margin="83,85,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=price, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="23" Margin="83,136,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button Content="Save to grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding ParameterCommand, Source={StaticResource modelview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource order}}"/>

</Grid>
```

Commands also attaching in case any problem is there

```
namespace WpfApplication2.ViewModels.Commands
{
  public class ParameterCommand : ICommand
  {

    public ViewModel ViewMod
    {
        get ;
        set ;
    }

    public ParameterCommand(ViewModel view)
    {
        this.ViewMod = view;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.ViewMod.ParameterMethod(parameter as Order);
    }
  }
}
```

**ADDED**
Main Window.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        //ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        //this.DataContext = vm;

    }


   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        New win = new New();
        win .Owner = this;
        win .DataContext = this.DataContext;
        win .Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using Resources in your NewWindow ? I think they are not needed at all.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan
Command="{Binding ParameterCommand, Source={StaticResource modelview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource order}}

Using resources to bind it to button command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's cause you are creating new object of `ViewModel` in new `window` and using data as `DataContext`. try below code:

```
Window w = new Window();
w.DataContext = this.DataContext;
w.Show();
```

When you open the new `window`, use current `DataContext` instance as new window's `DataContext`. And your code will work fine.

**Update**

Remove below part from you `New Window`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <view:Order x:Key="order"></view:Order>
    <model:ViewModel x:Key="modelview"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Cause of `<model:ViewModel x:Key="modelview"/>` a new object of `ViewModel` is being created with the `New Window`.

Change your `Command` as following:

```
<Button Content="Save to grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding ParameterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource order}}"/>
```

> Not sure what are you trying to do in `CommandParameter`. But your New
>   Window is getting existing `ViewModel` object as `DataContext`.
>   `Command` can be directly bound to `Button`.

Comment: It is still creating a new object of viewmodel

Comment: @ZainAwais how did you infer or conclud that?

Comment: @ZainAwais have you removed DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource order}}" code from new window? it is not required after you have given DataContext to  window.

Comment: Used debugging on Initialized Component of the the new window. it is again going in the constructor and initializing it. Attaching Code below

Comment: please see the updated question and help me where i am wrong

Comment: @ZainAwais it will go to new window constructor every time you new button. A new Window will be created but they all will share same DataContext "modelview" which was created with the initialization of MainWindow in XAML. What problem now you are facing exactly?

Comment: i want to use the same obervablecollection throughout the program . but here new window is going to the constructor of viewmodel. creating new observablecollection not using the collection created in mainwindow. I want to make change in the Observablecollection of mainwindow from newwindow